# Editing variables in GitLab CI and ensuring they are safe

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a multi-project pipeline in GitLab. The first project in the pipeline triggers a build of the second project.

At the moment the first project passes two variables to the next project - one variable holds the name of the project $CI_PROJECT_NAME and the other the URL of the project $CI_PROJECT_URL. these are both required in the second project.

In the second project I require the $CI_PROJECT_URL variable to perform

```
git clone https://oauth2:$ACCESS_TOKEN@${CI_PROJECT_URL}
```

So my first question is: how do I go about removing the **https://** at the start of CI_PROJECT_URL? It doesn't work with the https://, though it does if I hardcode the url without it. A simple question I'm sure, though I just cannot figure it out!

My second question. I need to check both $CI_PROJECT_NAME and $CI_PROJECT_URL for anything malicious, such as new lines, additional commands, etc, added after the variable declaration in the first project. For reference the $CI_PROJECT_URL will look like this, albeit with a different project name and username: https://projects.dep.place.co.uk/username/project_1. What would the recommended approach to this problem be?

I was also trying to find out if it was possible to simply access the project url that triggered the build of the second project from the second project. If that was possible it would bypass this issue altogether. Is this possible in any way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For you first question, you can build the URL without the http protocol with some of the other predefined variables Gitlab CI provides each running job. Try this in one of your jobs and see if it's correct:

```
...
script:
  - echo "${CI_SERVER_HOST}:${CI_SERVER_PORT}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}"
```

For your second question, each of these variables, including `$CI_PROJECT_TITLE` (the name of your project), are provided by Gitlab CI itself, they're not user-supplied, so you can trust that these values will always be what they're described to be when you use them in your pipelines.

You can view all the predefined variables Gitlab CI provides here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html